# How to rename files by creation date in OSX?

Tags: macos, date, ubuntu

I'm looking to create a solution to rename files by the creation date `yy-mm-dd` and not the actual date for Mac and Ubuntu.  I already know how to create an app with AppleScript and call it hourly with `launchd` and Ubuntu  use a CRON job when files are sent to the repo for storage that do not have the creation date at the beginning of the file.

I can rename files by today's date with:

```
for file in *.zip; do
    mv -n "$file" "$(date +%Y%m%d_"$file")"
done
```

but when I try:

```
for f in *.zip; do
    D=$(stat -n '%Y%m%d' $f)
    mv -v "$f" "$D_$f"
done
```

nothing happens.  I am able to use `stat foobar.zip` to get the date of the file but is there a way I can do this for the creation date so when I write my conditional to test if a date doesn't exist to apply the creation date?  I somewhat recall being able to do `date -r` in Ubuntu but that isn't available on Mac.  I've searched on SO, AskUbuntu and Unix but I am unable to find a solution that would allow me the option to do this.  I thought about testing with `stat` and `awk` to set as the variable `D` and rename it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
D=$(date -r $(stat -f %B $f) +%Y%m%d)
```

`$(...)` will execute a command and insert the output into the command line. We do this twice: first `stat -f %B $f` executes, with `$f` substituted with the current file; `-f %B` means "gimme inode birth time as UNIX timestamp". This will produce something like `1440737362` as output; next, this value is inserted into the next layer, and `date -r 1440737362 +%Y%m%d` is executed. This will convert the UNIX timestamp into the YYmmdd format: `20150828`. This is again inserted into the next outer layer, and we get `D=20150828`, which assigns the human-readable-ish ctime to the variable `D`.

EDIT: changed `%c` (inode change time) to `%B` (inode birth time)

Comment: I get `stat: a: stat: No such file or directory` so I changed it to `$(stat -f %c $f)` and nothing happens: `foobar.zip -> foobar.zip`.  Do you mind explaining what is going on in your answer to help others?

Comment: Ah right that was my test file name, forgot to change it. Did you replace just your `mv`? Or did you replace both statements? If you put in `echo $D` into your loop, what does it show?

Comment: Yes when I run `echo $D` it is today's date.  Not the date the file was created, in this case 2012-04-16.

Comment: I'm on OSX 10.11.4

Comment: I don't think the tiny version difference should matter. Silly question, but are you sure your file is not created today? `ls -lU filename`

Comment: yes I am sure, the output of `ls -lU filename` -> `-rwxr-xr-x  1 darth_vader  staff  6647855 Apr 18  2012 test.zip`

Comment: Oh, I think I see. Try `%B` (inode birth time) instead of `%c` (inode change time) for `stat`?

Answer (score 6):

**Complete Example**

The solution by Amadan was very helpful and of course correct. Maybe like me, others are searching for the finished example. I figured it out and it looks like this:

one-liner:

```
for f in *.jpg; do D=$(date -r $(stat -f %B $f) +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S); mv "$f" "$D-$f"; done
```

readable version:

```
for file in *.jpg
  do VARIABLE_DATE_OF_FILE=$(date -r $(stat -f %B $file) +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)
  mv "$file" "$VARIABLE_DATE_OF_FILE-$file"
done
```

Comment: Thanks! Also had to update for uppercase extensions `.JPG`

Answer (score 2):

I tried the example from Phlow, and it irrecoverably deleted all my files. It's missing quotes around the $f in the stat command. The solution should have read:

`for f in *.jpg; do D=$(date -r $(stat -f %B "$f") +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S); mv "$f" "$D-$f"; done`

Comment: this is the best answer ... doesn't account for spaces otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `date` on macOS to get your desired format. Just do this:

```
stat -f %SB -t "%y-%m-%d" FILE
```

The `%S` tells `stat` to format the following data item (here `B`) as a string and the `-t` option tells stat how dates are formatted as strings.